# including extra context value django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework. I need to pass some extra context value in response but not getting extra_value in response.

```
class ResultRowView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class    = ResultRowSerializer
    permission_classes  = (AccountPermission, )

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {'extra_value': 5000}
        return self.serializer_class(*args, context=context, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = ResultRow.objects.none()
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        try:
            route = IncomingRoute.objects.get(account=self.request.user.account, pk=pk)
            qs = route.app_module.rows.all()
        except Exception, e:
            print 'result_row_query: ', e
        return qs
```

What is missing here ?

Comment: What is `extra_value ` ?

Comment: I need to pass an extra context value and suppose its value is 5000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this by overriding the list method like:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(ResultRowView, self).list(request, args, kwargs)
    response.data[ 'extra_value' ] = 5000
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the get_context_data method and then add context to it

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PropertyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['some_key'] = some_value
    return context
```

Comment: there is no get_context_data in listAPIView